# Python merge/append only new excel files

Tags: python, excel, csv, merge, append

Below is the code that I run to merge all my excel files. The CSV is done pretty quick, however the excel merge takes longer. What I do is drag and drop new excel files in the folder, run the code to output a single updated file. However, it's starting to take longer. What can I do to make it append with only newly dropped files?

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir(r"myinputfolder")
extension = 'xlsx'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_xlsx = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f,'Download') for f in all_filenames ])
os.chdir(r"myoutputfolder")
combined_xlsx.to_excel( "combined_xlsx.xlsx", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Are you concatenating all the files every single time, or do you just concatenate the most recent result with the newest file?

Comment: Yes I run the code to concatenate all the files in the folder. I would like the script to only concatenate/append the new files that i drop in the folder every other day.

Comment: Do you have the files elsewhere, too, can you remove them from the folder?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow?

Comment: I think it'll be clearer if I explain what I had in mind: Run the program once now, concatenating all the Excel files you currently have. Then, add the resulting file (we can call it v1) to an empty folder. The next time you add a new file to the folder, have the script add it to v1, creating the file v2, and remove v1 and the new file, leaving only v2 in the folder. Repeat each time you add a new file.

Comment: Of course, that isn't exactly an ideal solution. Can you provide some more context for this? How many files will there be, and how large are they? Is there any way you could use a different file format, for example?

Comment: I was thinking the same, but yes, it isn't ideal. I add a daily report file in the folder, but after a month those 30 files are replaced by one single monthly report, followed by the next daily reports etc. 

How can i program in python where python picks up all 10 .xlsx, concat, delete the files and then export?

The file size is 10mb, mainly because they contain pivots.

Comment: Can't use different format. The files are exported using a program which only exports xlsx files with pivot tables. But the file contains a sheet that has raw data which is the one where I pull all data from.

Comment: ok doing this now

`shutil.rmtree(r"\Python\test")
os.chdir(r"\Python\test")
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')`

but i get error: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: mydirector


If i run the code line by line, it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the cause of the issue, but there's no reason to always be using `os.chdir()`, no?

Comment: yes i added it as a comment, no luck. I also tried adding 5 second gap, everything works fine up until the last line where it writes file. Only solution is to manually click last line to run.

I don't mind but i have other folders to work with, so it will save me time if there is a way to run the file without error.

Comment: _I also tried adding 5 second gap, everything works fine up until the last line where it writes file. Only solution is to manually click last line to run._ That's really bizarre. Can you add the new/modified program to your post?

Comment: Did you manage to figure things out?

Comment: Hello, i used os.remove(file) and it works fine. It's using a loop format, so first it converts xlsx to csv, then removes xlsx and then appends the original csv file.


And because converted CSV files are blazing fast to work with, i decided to keep them for future purposes.

Comment: You should answer your own question, eh, share the code.

Comment: done haha, took me long time tho

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

#excel to csv 
source= r'C:\Users\'
dest= r'C:\Users\'
os.chdir(source)

for file in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
       df = pd.read_excel(file, 'sheet1')
       df.to_csv(dest+file+'.csv', index=False)
       os.remove(file)
#append

os.chdir(r"C:\Users")
extension = 'csv'
all_Ph = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
Ph = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_Ph ])
Ph.drop(Ph.columns[[0, 3, 7, 10]], axis=1, inplace=True)
os.chdir(r"C:\Users")
Ph.to_csv( "xhtfr.csv", index=False)
```